# How to override RSpec's filter_run_excluding in RubyMine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, rubymine

Is it possible to get RubyMine to ignore the spec_helper.rb filters?
I usually add `config.filter_run_excluding :js => true`in my spec_helper file so that when running just rspec it excludes all js tests by default (because the js tests are usually slow).

But when I edit a file in RubyMine I would like to be able to run that single test, and get RubyMine to ignore the `config.filter_run_excluding :js => true`.

The way I solve it now is to comment out the line in the spec_helper.rb and then run the single test in RubyMine, but it would be nice to get that behaviour by default in RubyMine..

**Versions**

- RubyMine 6.3.3
- rspec-rails (2.14.1)
- rails 4.0.4

I know I can also just remove the exclude filters in spec_helper and stop using just RSpec for running all the tests, and use `rspec -tag ~js`, but I would really like to just override the spec_helper filters in RubyMine and not in the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably by using an environment variable.

Surround that configuration line in spec_helper with a check for an environment variable

```
unless ENV['INCLUDE_JS']
  config.filter_run_excluding :js => true
end
```

and add `INCLUDE_JS=1` to the RSpec Run/Debug Configurations that you want to not exclude Javascript specs. If you want to do it for all Run/Debug Configurations, add the environment variable to the RSpec default and it will propagate to new configurations when they are created.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I would very much like to only add configurations in RubyMine and not in the spec_helper file. There is a [Runner options](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-rspec.html) choice in Defaults for rspec in RubyMine I would think I could add tags there like: --tag js, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think there's a bug in RubyMine: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-15547 I think it's a non-issue for this question, because I don't think there's a way to do what you want only using RSpec options (which is why I gave the answer I did): on the command line, `--tag js` overrides `filter_run_excluding`, but runs only examples tagged `js`; I tried `--tag js --tag ~js`, but that just behaves like `--tag ~js`. At least you only need to add the environment variable check to spec_helper.rb once, or maybe once for each tag that you use `filter_run_excluding` for.

Comment: Ok. Then I guess environment variable is the best solution. Thank you very much for your answer and comments.